# NameError when importing function from another script?

Tags: python, python-import

I am having difficulty importing a function from another script. Both of the scripts below are in the same directory. Why can't the function from another script handle an object with the same name (`arr`)?

**evens.py**

```
def find_evens():
    return [x for x in arr if x % 2 == 0]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = list(range(11))

    print(find_evens())
```

**import_evens.py**

```
from evens import find_evens

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = list(range(11))

    print(find_evens())
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\import_evens.py", line 7, in <module>
    find_evens()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\evens.py", line 2, in find_evens
    return [x for x in arr if x % 2 == 0]
NameError: name 'arr' is not defined
```

Comment: try using a relative import: `from .evens import find_evens`

Comment: You should pass `arr` in as a function argument instead, and define `find_evens` to take a parameter (e.g. `def find_evens(arr): ...` and calling it with `find_evens(arr)`)

Comment: Well, `arr` doesn't get defined in `evens.py` when it is being imported (because then it's not `__main__`). And it won't see the `arr` defined in `import_evens.py`.

Comment: I *could* pass that as an argument, but I would rather have these functions work on global variables

Comment: No, you wouldn't. Really, trust us, you *don't* want global variables.

Comment: Add this here for people who find this later. ["Why are global variables evil?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). Thanks for the input, everyone. Always learning new things about coding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules in python have separate namespaces. The qualified names `evens.arr` and `import_evens.arr` are separate entities. In each module, using just the name `arr` refers to the one local to it, so `arr` in `import_evens` is actually `import_evens.arr`.

Since you are defining `arr` inside of `if __name__ ...`, the name `arr` is only the defined in the *executed* module. The name `evens.arr` is never defined.

Further, there is no notion of truly global names. A name can be global to a module, so all entities inside it can use it. Any other module still has to address it as `a_module.global_variables_name`. It can also be imported as `from a_module import global_variables_name`, but this is just sugar for importing it and binding it to a *new* local name.

```
# same as `from a_module import global_variables_name`
import a_module
global_variables_name = a_module.global_variables_name
```

---

What you have shown is best done via parameters to the function:

```
# evens.py
def find_evens(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if x % 2 == 0]

# import_evens.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = list(range(11))
    print(find_evens(arr))
```

If you think it's better to have global variables for this but don't understand how a language uses global variables, it's better not to have global variables.